# How to know jar process

Tags: command-line, process

I launched on server, by crontab few jar (java) files (part1.jar, part2.jar...).

I can get are data of process:

```
lsof -i tcp:8080

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    15287 root   26u  IPv6 3242442      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

How to know which exactly jar file running now? I am mean name of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lsof it self for same activity. Execute below command in your terminal

`lsof | grep 15287`